# Exclude placeholders on validation in IE8

Tags: html, validation, internet-explorer-8, placeholder

I'm using a  [jquery placeholder plugin](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to show placeholders in ie8. I'm also using [jquery live validation](http://livevalidation.com/javascripts/src/1.3/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js) for validating my forms. Now in IE8 all the placeholders are taken as values. In my form, phone number is not mandatory field, yet should be validated if user enters some value. Placeholder for my phone number field is "Phone Number" which is not valid as it becomes value in IE8. Please suggest me a way not to validate placeholders in iE8.

Now in iE8 if the user clicks submit without entering phone number field, live validation plugin is validating the phone number field taking placeholder as value.

Comment: Please put some runnable code into a `JSFiddle`. That would make it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to read the docs before posting on SO:

> The plugin automatically adds class="placeholder" to the elements who are currently showing their placeholder text.

So, if your user enters a phone number, the `placeholder` class will be removed by the plugin. You can check for that class using `$("input#phoneNumber").hasClass("placeholder")`.